# C pointers: how to say this code

Tags: c, pointers

I found this page with the following explanation of pointers:
http://www.woyouxian.net/c/c0501.html

```
int x = 1, y = 2, z[10];
int *ip;          /* ip is a pointer to int */
ip = &x;          /* ip now points to x */
y = *ip;          /* y is now 1 */
*ip = 0;          /* x is now 0 */
ip = &z[0];       /* ip now points to z[0] */
```

However, the lines *"y is now 1"* and *"x is now 0"* describe the results, not the code. How would one "say" those lines, to describe the code (as the other lines do)?

In other words, the line *"y is now 1"* does not implicitly have the literal "1" on the line, so the description is describing the result of the code and not the code itself. I'd like a description of the code itself.

Comment: They are labeled "y is now 1" and "x is now 0" because those descriptions help new programmers understand that the value of x is linked to ip. Those descriptions are probably more beneficial than those posted below.

Comment: @k.shroeder31: Hard to disagree with that. Were I a teacher, I'd probably stick with them for a basic class. Still, I think that the OP is asking for terser descriptions, having read and understood the introductory annotations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C is not a spoken language, so opinions here will vary quite considerably.

I'd say and comment it like this:

```
int x = 1, y = 2, z[10];
int *ip;          /* declares a pointer-to-int called "ip" */
ip = &x;          /* makes "ip" point to "x" */
y = *ip;          /* sets "y" to the value of what "ip" points to, i.e. 1 */
*ip = 0;          /* sets the value of what "ip" points to to 0 */
ip = &z[0];       /* makes "ip" point to the first element in the array "z" */
```

Or, to stay closer to your original comments:

```
int x = 1, y = 2, z[10];
int *ip;          /* ip is a pointer to int */
ip = &x;          /* ip now points to x */
y = *ip;          /* y's value is now equal to the value of the object that "ip" points to */
*ip = 0;          /* the value of the object that "ip" points is now 0 */
ip = &z[0];       /* ip now points to z[0] */
```

---

#### Disclaimer

I wouldn't actually write comments like this into code. Code comments are for explaining *rationale*; code syntax should be self-explanatory.

What I meant was that I'd *annotate* the code like that, if I had to for a purpose like yours.

Answer (score 3):

The line `y = *ip` means "assuming 'ip' is a pointer (i.e. a memory address), go to its memory address, retrieve the value, and store it in variable `y`". Since the previous line set `ip` to the address of `x`, whose value was 1, the value of y after executing that line is also 1.

The line `*ip = 0` means "go to the address stored in `ip` (i.e. the address of `x`'s value), and set the value there to 0.

Answer (score 2):

```
int x = 1; /* create a integer variable x and set it to 1 */
int y = 2; /* create a integer variable y and set it to 2 */
int z[10]; /* create a list z of 10 integers  */
int *ip; /* create a pointer to an intger ip */
ip = &x; /* let ip point to the variable x */
y = *ip; /* let y be the value that ip points at */
*ip = 0; /* set the value that ip points at to 0 */
ip = &z[0]; /* let ip point at the first value in the list z */
```

Comment: +1: I could be really pedantic and point out the difference between "values" and "objects" (or "variables" if you like), but I won't. :) This is certainly good enough annotation for an introductory C resource.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
int x = 1, y = 2, z[10];
int *ip;          /* declare ip as a pointer to an int */
ip = &x;          /* assign the address of x to ip (i.e. the value of ip is now the address of x) */
y = *ip;          /* assign y to the value of the memory at which ip points */
*ip = 0;          /* assign the value of the memory at which ip points to 0 */
ip = &z[0];       /* assign ip the address of the first element of the z array */
```

Comment: You mixed descriptions of actions with descriptions of results.

Comment: Just on two lines. Fixed anyway.

Comment: Better :D "Just on two lines" is quite significant in fact: note that the OP is asking about "just" two lines!

Comment: Thanks= you, Seth, these explanations are excellent. You seem to have really understood what I was trying to get at. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`y = *ip` : Set the value of the variable `y` to what `ip` points to.

`*ip = 0` : Set the value of the pointer `ip` to `0`. Since `ip` is a pointer,`*ip` accesses what `ip` is pointing to.

Side note (handy terminology): In both of the above, `*` is used to **dereference** the pointer `ip`.

Comment: Thank you about the terminology note. That is handy!

Answer (score 0):

I generally pronounce "x = 1" as "x becomes 1". Others might say "x is 1" or "x equals 1".

In your code, I would say "y becomes the value pointed to by ip" and "the value pointed to by ip becomes 0".

Comment: I like "set `x` to 1", maintaining the "this is an order" mentality rather than describing my code like a story.

Comment: Comments describe the code, though. In the olden days of Basic, I'd say "let x become 1" or even "let x be 1". Sound a bit like "let there be light". <g>

Comment: Comments should describe the _rationale_ behind code, not the code itself. If the code syntax is not self-explanatory, then something is wrong. In this case, the "comments" are more like annotations for teaching purposes, not actual documenting code comments that would be written into an actual product.

Comment: Comments should not be overused. The comments you see are only used in texts for beginners, to explain what actually happens. No professional text would contain such comments, as it is assumed that other professionals can read it without them. Comments should explain processes and the rationale, indeed. What is the rationale to assign 1 to x in the code you posted? To show beginners what happens.

Comment: I completely agree. I think I said that :)

Answer (score 0):

"the value of the address ip points to is copied into y"

"the value 0 is copied into the address ip points to"

Answer (score 0):

```
y = *ip;    /* y is now the value stored in location pointed by ip */
*ip = 0;    /* value stored in location pointed by ip is now 0 */
```